# How to determine whether a Range are overlapping with another Range in different lists and by how much?

Tags: python, list, range

Bit difficult to explain so I have an example below.

So I have List A which looks like this - `(20-40,60-80,100-200)` But they can be any ranges.

And List B `(15-35,60-85,50-150)` and as you can see the three range in B do cross over with those in A but I need to easily determine whether they do (Some don't) and by how much they 'mis-align' or by how much they are different. For example, for the first element in both lists, B overlaps but is 5 too low at the start and stop of the range.

My only thought so far is to create a very slow 'for loop' system which checks the ranges but this is incredibly slow for the large numbers of values I have.

I thought this would be a trivial problem but I haven't found anything simple as of yet. Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Start by writing a boolean function to check if two ranges overlap. That way you don't have to hold so much logic in your head while writing the algorithm.

Comment: Your "Lists" aren't Python `list`s. What are they then, strings?

Comment: what if A = [10-50, 60-90 ] and B = [ 5-65, 45-95 ] what should be the output? or is it 1-1 list comparison?

Comment: These are python lists but I split them just to get raw int values for the ranges and I would like the output to be deciding if a range in A is overlapping with one in B and if so by how much.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to make the assumption that the lists of ranges are sorted and do not overlap within themselves. If that's not true, this answer will need to modify somewhat.

First, lets write a helper function save us the hassle of checking if two ranges overlap.

```
def compare(r1, r2):
    low_1, high_1, low_2, high_2 = parse(r1, r2) # parse is left as an exercise because I'm lazy
    if (high_1 < low_2):
        return -1
    elif (high_2 < low_1):
        return 1
    return 0 # They overlap!
```

Now that we have the helper function, we can implement a seeking algorithm based on our assumptions from the beginning.

```
def seek(list_of_ranges_1, list_of_ranges_2):
len_1 = len(list_of_ranges_1)
len_2 = len(list_of_ranges_2)
head_1, head_2 = 0

while(true):
    # Given that the lists are sorted, if you reach the end of one, there are no more overlaps
    if (head_1 == len_1 || head_2 == len_2):
       break
    r1 = list_of_ranges_1[head_1]
    r2 = list_of_ranges_2[head_2]
    test_value = compare(r1,r2)
    if (test_value == -1):
       head_1 +=1
    elif (test_value == 1):
       head_2 +=1
    else:
        # This is the complicated case. In the other cases, there was no overlap, 
        # so we could safely move the lower range forward. But now, we 
        # have ranges that overlap, and there could be several ranges in
        # one list that overlap with a single range in the first list.
        # The solution to this is to iterate the range that has the lower 
        # high_value. IE, if we has r1 = 10-15 and r2 = 12-25, we would 
        # iterate head_1, but if r2 was 12-13, we would iterate head_2, to account for
        # the possibility that the next range is 14-n, and overlaps with the 
        # same range 10-15.
```

This code, assuming that the parse function and the else case are properly implemented, will achieve the result you want. Also, give that head_1 and head_2 are strictly increasing on each iteration of the loops, the complexity is O(n + m).

Comment: Hm, I just saw that even in your example, the ranges were overlapping within list B (60-85 overlaps with 50-150). I'm thinking about ways to account for that without losing linear time.

Comment: Yes they may not be sorted and can overlap

Comment: The fact that they're not sorted is no big deal, just define a compare function (maybe even the compare function I wrote up there) and apply the sorting algorithm of your choice. That increases complexity to O(nlogn), but that's still better than the n^2 you had earlier. The issue is that ranges may overlap in the lists themselves. Are you able to modify the lists to prevent that, or would that destroy some of the information you're looking to capture? IE, Do you care that (10-15) overlaps with both (11-15) and (12-13)?